# How do I convert from a date to string in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, date

I need to treat a **date** field in mySQL as if it is a **string**.  For the purposes of using the date in a LIKE statement:

`select * from table where dob like some_string;`

Doing this currently produces the following warning:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect date value: '1492' for column 'dob' at row 1 |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get a string representation of your DATE column:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '1492%';
```

and use the pattern that suits your need best. You find the specifiers right in the linked manual page.

**Note:**

MySQL can't use an index for this kind of query, so it will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cast

```
Select * 
From   Table 
Where  Cast(dob as nvarchar(20)) Like some_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

> using the date in a LIKE statement

No. Things that this approach does wrong:

- Wastes CPU time converting dates to strings.
- Wastes time doing string comparisons when integer comparisons could be done.
- Throws away any index on `dob` that might otherwise make the query more efficient.

A better approach would be something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE dob BETWEEN '1492-01-01' AND '1492-12-31'
```

You will always want to do as few type conversions as possible and keep the table data as-is so that indexes are properly utilized.